# JS/JQ Fix for Son of Suckerfish extending below fold?

Tags: jquery, viewport, suckerfish

I am creating a dropdown (well, actually it popups out to the right) navigation menu using "Son of Suckerfish."

Some of the sub menus are quite long and fall below the fold. Is there a way (using JavaScript/jQuery) to ensure that the menus are always above the fold (I'm quite happy if ones that are too big to fit in the viewport just butt up to the top)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I couldn't find an answer, so made a solution myself.

The following is the code I used (requires jQuery):

```
var winHeight = $(window).height();
$navULs = $('#nav ul');
$navULs.find('ul').each(function(i,v) {
    $this = $(v);
    var ulHeight = $this.height();
    var parentHeight = $this.closest('li').height();
    var parentTop = $this.offset().top;
    var parentBottom = parentTop + parentHeight;
    if ((winHeight - parentTop) &lt; ulHeight) {
        if (parentBottom &lt; ulHeight) {
            $this.css({
                'margin-top': '0px',  // remove margin-top (added by suckerfish css) as it screws up the calculations
                'top': '-' + (parentTop) + 'px'  // move the menu up by the amount of px available above the parent's top
            });
        } else {
            $this.css('bottom', '0px');  // v basic, if sub menu will drop too much shove it up (css does the heavy lifting here)
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried to explain it in this [blog post](http://www.atwright.co.uk/blog/2013/07/keep-vertical-son-of-suckerfish-above-the-fold).